# LWJGL can't change display if it's a different frequency

Tags: java, exception, fullscreen, lwjgl, frequency

Using a Windows 7 64-bit computer and a monitor that supports different refresh rates: 24hz, 30hz, 59hz, 60hz.

I have a small LWJGL application that sets the fullscreen display mode to "1280 x 720 @60hz"

If my current display mode is "1920 x 1080 @30hz" and I execute my application, I get a LWJGLException:

```
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Failed to set display mode (-2).
```

If I change my application to set the fullscreen display mode to "1280 x 720 @30hz", it works perfect.

I can only change fullscreen display modes that have the same frequency of the current display mode. In this case 30hz.

I know it's not my computer nor my monitor, because I tried some videogames that allow to change the frequency, and they didn't crash.

What could be the problem? I've tried many codes for changing the display, and they all get the same LWJGLException.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the complete list of display modes that Java thinks your monitor supports by calling [GraphicsDevice.getDisplayModes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsDevice.html#getDisplayModes%28%29). It is typical to ask the user to choose from this list rather than assuming a particular resolution is supported. If you do want to specify a resolution, you can use `DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN` as the refresh rate; it will then pick whatever rate the monitor supports for that resolution.

Comment: You are confusing java.awt.DisplayMode with org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode, but thanks for replying. I do have a list with all "supported" display modes. The thing is 90% are 60hz, the rest are 24hz, 59hz, 30hz. So if a user happens to have his display mode set to 30hz and wants to change it to another one that is 60hz, the application will crash. So even if I give the user a list with "only 30hz displays", he will not have all the display modes. I want the user to choose any display with any frequency available.